# Benefits of 802.11ac routers for home networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an old (2008) router for domestic networks which supports the 802.11g standard. It continues working quite well even if the number of devices in my network increased consistently recently (relatively speaking: it passed from two or three devices constantly connected to 8 or 9 devices). I've two main issues with it: the first is a limited coverage (about 5, 6 meters), because when I got it, this was not an issue at all, so I didn't spend extra money for unnedeed features. There is only one room in my house where the signal is too low and I fixed this inconvenient adding an extender (at which, however, only one device at time can be connected). The second problem, the most annoying, is that after some time I need to reboot the router in order Chromecast can be found by the other devices and the device connected to the extender can reach the internet. Sometimes, more than one reboot is needed.

I think that the problem may be mainly due to the fact that, at that time, routers for home networking were designed to handle only one or two WiFi devices and that a greater number of devices makes it difficult, for them, keeping sync and easier getting out of memory (things that can be exacerbated when there are low-signal devices, I believe). Indeed, usually a refresh of the memory and a new synchronization with the ISP (i.e., a reboot) makes things right. Surfing the Internet, I learned that newer routers support the 802.11ac standard and that this should be more suitable for accomodating the larger number of devices nowadays involved in home networks.

So my question is whether my thoughts were justified and if there was indeed a real (that is, intrisinc in the architecture) advantange in changing the router with one supporting the 802.11ac standard.

Comment: There are many factors, rebooting that often is NOT normal. 802.11ac will not support **more** clients afaik. It's the hardware of the router that supports many clients. I.e you can buy a economy AC router and get less performance than your current router. I have some quality wireless-n AP's that can handle 50+ associated clients. Do your research before you upgrade.

Comment: For all it may be worth to you, upgrading to 802.11ac or even 802.11n should resolve your weak signal in the one room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple advantages of upgrading - both to you and your neighbours - if you live in high density accommodation, not upgrading creates a tragedy of the commons.

Going from 802.11g to 802.11n means about 50-100% more range, but also better use of the spectrum + because 802.11n is much faster it allows better sharing if bandwidth.  Another advantage of  802.11n implementations is using multiple antennas to cancel noise and create better "virtual beams".

Going to 802.11ac means you will be using the 5ghz spectrum (and ac routers include support for 802.11n on the 2.4 gig band), and thus you will be freeing up more spectrum. The 5 gig band does not penetrate walls as well, so this is less likely to get overrun then the 2.4 gig spectrum.

The limited number of devices and/or reboots/disconnects is a sign of bad hardware/firmware, not something that can be blamed on the 802.11g standard. It is possible that radio Inteferrence and the resulting corruption of packets is contributing to your instability - but it's the routers processing of these - not the standard - that is the problem.